# context in visitor method returns null for sub expressions

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr, bnf

so:
(1) I'm just a beginner at this whole creating a compiler. (2) I will try hard and put in relevant bits about this, putting in all details would make this question just too long. I will monitor this question constantly for any details you guys need.

I'm trying to write a compiler for a simple expression/SQL like language, it should look/work like this:

```
Step 1: [Account Number] Greater Than [1];
Step Two: [Gender] Equals [M];
Step Last: Step 1 And Step Two;
```

So it's something like : `Step<Name>: [Field Name] Operator [Constant];` The constant can be numbers, if they aren't they'll be handled as strings. (So you could do [This is a Constant Value])

And then the last step has to be something that combines a bunch of other steps into a tree. Execution begins from the last step and all other steps are ignored.

---

**BUT, The problem** is .... I'm just trying to get one simple hard coded expression to work and I keep getting a **null for the Field Name inside one of the visit methods**.

All I'm trying to is make this ONE STEP program work:

```
Step 1: [Account Number] Equals [1];
```

This is the grammar file:

*Population.g4*

```
grammar Population;

@parser::members
{
    protected const int EOF = Eof;
}
@lexer::members
{
    protected const int EOF = Eof;
    protected const int HIDDEN = Hidden;
} 

/* Parser Rules */

prog: step;

step           : 'Step' .+ ':' field op=('Equals'|'Greater Than') numeric_const ';';

field          : FLD_REF;

numeric_const : 
                '[' INT ']' # NumericConst
                ;

/* Lexer Rules */

INT         : [0-9]+;
FLD_REF     : '[' .+ ']';
WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

*PopulationVisitor.cs*

```
public class PopulationVisitor : PopulationBaseVisitor<ICompilableExpression>
{
    public override ICompilableExpression VisitStep(PopulationParser.StepContext sCTX)
    {
        //**THIS IS THE PROBLEM**** ctx is always null
        PopulationParser.FieldContext ctx = sCTX.field();
        return base.VisitStep(sCTX);
    }
    public override ICompilableExpression 
                  VisitNumericConst(PopulationParser.NumericConstContext context)
    {
        int val = int.Parse(context.GetText();
        //I then use val to build an ICompilableExpression
    }
    public override ICompilableExpression 
                  VisitField(PopulationParser.FieldContext context)
    {
       //this ends up never being called.
    }
}
```

[image: Debugging the Visitor]

Why is the ctx null? But somehow if I change the grammar to this:

```
step : 'Step' .+ ':' FLD_REF op=('Equals'|'Greater Than') numeric_const ';';
```

NOW:

```
public override ICompilableExpression VisitStep(PopulationParser.StepContext context)
{
    var ctx = context.FLD_REF();
    //NOW, this returns an instance of ITerminalNode
    //and ctx is not null
    return base.VisitStep(context);
}
```

Why does the thing work if I use a lexer token but not a grammar rule that uses the SAME lex token!?

I bet there is something just basic in my understanding of all of this that is flawed. I would sincerely appreciate clues and/or help.

Comment: hey thanks so much for the reply @Bart didn't think about greediness there. I changed `FLD_REF` to `'{' .+? '}';` and then also changed  this `numeric_const :'<' INT '>'` but still when I type out a step line with `{` or `<` it still gives me a null for `context.field()` or `context.numeric_const()`

Comment: @BartKiers what you put as a comment worked for me and seemed to be the root of my problem everywhere. I was able to fix and finally complete my entire language by making a number regexes non-greedy. **Please put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.**

Comment: Cool, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+` is greedy, i.e. `'[' .+ ']'` grabs the first `'['` and the last `']'` (and everything in between, of course).

Try either `'[' .+? ']'` or `'[' ~[\]]+ ']'`